# How to get the value by column and row name in pandas in python

Tags: pandas

I am getting a co-occurrence matrix as follows using pandas.

```
lst = [
    ['a', 'b'],
    ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    ['a', 'd'],
    ['b', 'e']
]

u = (pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(lst), prefix='', prefix_sep='')
       .groupby(level=0, axis=1)
       .sum())

v = u.T.dot(u)
v.values[(np.r_[:len(v)], ) * 2] = 0

print(v)
```

My output is as follows.

```
   a  b  c  d  e
a  0  1  0  1  0
b  1  0  1  1  2
c  0  1  0  1  1
d  1  1  1  0  1
e  0  2  1  1  0
```

I want to get how many times **e** appears with **d** using the above matrix (i.e. `1`) and divide it by the total count of co-occurrences (i.e. `9` --> since the matix is symetric I only considered the upper part of the matrix to get the total sum).

So my output should be;

for co-occurrence count of e and d is 1.

[image]

and co-occurrence count of all should be 9 as follows (since the matrix is symetric).

[image]

I would like to know if it is possible do it in pandas.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work for you?

```
a=df.loc['e','b']
b=df.values.sum()/2
print((a/b))
```

inside the `loc` method, First value is row & the second value is column. you can change it as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need divide by sum of all values only for upper matrix, so divide `2`:

```
v = v / (v.values.sum() / 2)
print(v)
          a         b         c         d         e
a  0.000000  0.111111  0.000000  0.111111  0.000000
b  0.111111  0.000000  0.111111  0.111111  0.222222
c  0.000000  0.111111  0.000000  0.111111  0.111111
d  0.111111  0.111111  0.111111  0.000000  0.111111
e  0.000000  0.222222  0.111111  0.111111  0.000000
```

For one value:

```
print(v.loc['d','e'] / (v.values.sum() / 2))
0.1111111111111111
```

If need assign back ony one value:

```
v.loc['d','e'] = v.loc['d','e'] /v.values.sum() / 2
print(v)

   a  b  c  d         e
a  0  1  0  1  0.000000
b  1  0  1  1  2.000000
c  0  1  0  1  1.000000
d  1  1  1  0  0.111111
e  0  2  1  1  0.000000
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. I actually want to do it by specifying the column and row name. i.e. I give `e` and `d` and I get its co-occurrence count as `1`. next I get the total co-ocuurrence count seperately from the matrix (i.e. `9`) and later I divide it (i.e. 1/9 = 0.111111111). Is there a way to do this in pandas? :)

Comment: I updated the question. Please let me know if it is clear for you now. I dont want to update the whole matrix. I want to get the two values I have specified in the updated question. Thank you :)

Comment: @EmJ - So I think now understand, need scalar input? Answer was edited.

Comment: @jezrael  I think the out put expected is just one value. the porblem is to find the value in a particular location (for example intersection of row 'd' & column 'e' is 1, intersection of row 'e' & column 'b' is 2) and then divide this number by half the sum of the whole dataframe. In this sum of the whole dataframe is 18, so, half of it is 9. I have provided a solution, may be you can provide a even better one.

Comment: ok! got it. saw the update only now. But the answer seems wrong. 1/9 should be 0.1111, not 0.027777777777777776. I double checked with the calculator on my computer.

Comment: @mohanys - You are right, missing () for me. Now working nice.